# Ambiguous column name 'created_at'. MSSQL 2008 Server + Kaminari + Rails 3.2.13 + JDBC

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, jdbc

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm not so sure this is Kaminari specific or JDBC issue. When I execute rails code below to paginate, got the error as shown below. Obviously MSSQL wants 'issues.created_at DESC' instead of just 'created_at DESC', but I'm not so sure how can I do this. Thanks in advance for any help..

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ambiguous column name 'created_at'.:
```

Gemfile has:

`gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', "~> 1.3.2"`

`gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter', "~> 1.3.2"`

Code in Controller

`@issues = @issues.page(params[:page]).per(20)`

produces

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - ActiveRecord::JDBCError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ambiguous column name 'created_at'.: SELECT t.* FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY state DESC, created_at DESC) AS _row_num, [issues].* FROM [issues] JOIN taggings issues_taggings_1ba8f24  ON issues_taggings_1ba8f24.taggable_id = issues.id AND issues_taggings_1ba8f24.taggable_type = N'Issue' AND issues_taggings_1ba8f24.tag_id = 2 WHERE [issues].[project_id] = 11 AND ([issues].[state] IN (N'opened',N'reopened')) ) AS t WHERE t._row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 20:`

Comment: What is generating that OVER? Something beyond your control?

Comment: I believe Kaminari is doing it, for sort records.

Comment: Any idea where the `state desc` and `created_at desc` are coming from? Are they in `params[:page]` somewhere?

Comment: I traced it and it was coming from `@issues = @project.issues`. So   Project `has_many :issues, dependent: :destroy, order: "state DESC, created_at DESC"`. I just replaced with table alias in the order clause  and it works fine.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own questions and even accept your own answers (after a day or so). AFAIK, questions with accepted answers are usually easier to find so it is worthwhile.